# Custom instance variables and initializing with PetitParser

Tags: initialization, instance-variables, pharo, petitparser

As far as I know *PetitParser* initializes each instance variable with a production method of the same name. What should one do, to add a custom instance variable and initialize it in the `initialize` method for example?

Comment: that's only true for subclasses of PPCompositeParser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the class-side method `#ignoredNames` in subclasses to add your own instance-variables that PetitParser does not touch:

```
PPCompositeParser class>>#ignoredNames
    "Answer a collection of instance-variables that should 
     not be automatically initialized with productions, but
     that are used internal to the composite parser."

     ^ PPCompositeParser allInstVarNames
```